# Is the following sum manipulation correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am wondering if someone can confirm the following, or point out an error:
$$
2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sum_{j=1}^{n-i}x_{i+j} = 2(\sum_{i=1}x_i\sum_{i+1}^nx_j) = (\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{i+1}^nx_j) + (\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j)
= \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{j\not =i}x_j
$$

I guess I'm pretty confident the above is correct, but I'm not quite sure how I could rigorously show the way I split it into two sums is correct (which is the part I am concerned about)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=3$, this yields

$$2(x_1(x_1+x_2)+x_2x_1)=x_1(x_2+x_3)+x_2(x_1+x_3)+x_3(x_1+x_2).$$

So, no.

Comment: Had a typo that I just fixed, sorry. Still doesn't work though, I guess. So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Edited, you wrote

$\begin{array}\\
2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sum_{j=1}^{n-i}x_{i+j} 
&= 2(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{j=i+1}^nx_j)\\
&= (\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{j=i+1}^nx_j) + (\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j)
\qquad\text{(the second sum is wrong)}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{j\not =i}x_j\\
\end{array}
$

Your error in the second line
is that you assumed that
$\sum_{j=i+1}^nx_j
=\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j
$.

I don't know why you wrote this,
but it is clearly wrong.
In particular,
$j > i$ in the first sum
and
$j < i$ in the second sum.